# Group by clause and list

Tags: mysql, sql, database

> GROUP BY: If you want, you can take the rows that remain after WHERE and put them in groups or buckets, where each group contains the same value for the GROUP BY expression (and all the other rows are put in a list for that group). In Java, you would get something like: `Map<String, List<Row>>`. If you do specify a GROUP BY clause, then your actual rows contain only the group columns, no longer the remaining columns, which are now in that list. Those columns in the list are only visible to aggregate functions that can operate upon that list.

This above paragraph was taken from: https://blog.jooq.org/a-beginners-guide-to-the-true-order-of-sql-operations/

We have a table named student that has the following fields :

- Student_id
- Student_name
- Student_marks
- Student_branch

I write a query as:

```sql
select sum(student_marks) from student
group by student_branch;
```

So according to the paragraph, I am grouping the rows by student_branch.
So what group is created?
Is there a group that contains all of the student_branch values?
Also I couldn't get the meaning of this sentence '(and all the other rows are put in a list for that group).'

Can anyone please explain how does group by actually work and then how do the aggregate functions work on those groups.

Answer (score 0):

In your example you would have a separate group for each distinct value in the column `student_branch`. So if you you have `student_branch = A` for 5 students and `student_branch = B` for 3 students, then you would get 2 groups:

- `A` with 5 records
- `B` with 3 records

When you use aggregate functions, they will operate on all records within one group. So `SUM(student_marks)` will add all student marks of the students in group A separately, and also in group B separately.

In your sample query you will get 2 aggregated result rows, with only the sums of the marks. The result would be more meaningful, if you include the `student_branch` in the `SELECT` clause, like:

```
SELECT student_branch, SUM(student_marks) AS sum_of_marks FROM student
GROUP BY student_branch;
```

Then the result would look like:

| student_branch | sum_of_marks |
| --- | --- |
| A | 15 (random number, = sum of marks for A students) |
| B | 8 (random number, = sum of marks for B students) |

The `GROUP BY` will only group the records which remain after filtering the data with the `WHERE` clause. In your example case there is no `WHERE` clause, so it will group the records of the whole table by student branch.